# Points in background don't show

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am creating a Android 2d space shooter as a way to learn OpenGL and want to have a starry background in the game. My idea is to just speckle the background with white points for a start but the dots dont show up. First is the renderer code:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    width = w;
    height = h;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // black background
    gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f);
    // clear the color buffer to show the ClearColor we called above...
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    stars.draw(gl);
}
```

Then the drawing of the stars:

```
private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private int count;

public Stars() {
    Random r = new Random();
    count = (int) ((r.nextFloat() * 200.0f) + 200.0f);
    count *= 3;

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(count * Float.SIZE);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    // allocate _count number of floats
    vertexBuffer = buffer.asFloatBuffer();

    float rVtx = (r.nextFloat() * 2.0f) - 1.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i += 3) {
        vertexBuffer.put(rVtx);
        rVtx = (r.nextFloat() * 2.0f) - 1.0f;

        vertexBuffer.put(rVtx);
        rVtx = (r.nextFloat() * 2.0f) - 1.0f;

        vertexBuffer.put(0.0f);
    }
}

public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glPointSize(3);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);

    gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_POINTS, 0, count / 3);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

What seems to be the error?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the default projection matrix in onSurfaceChanged. something like:

```
gl.glMatrixMode( GL10.GL_PROJECTION );                
gl.glLoadIdentity();        
gl.glOrthof( -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1 );

gl.glMatrixMode( GL10.GL_MODELVIEW );                 
gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

And at the end of the Stars(), put this as the last line:

```
vertexBuffer.position(0);
```

Comment: Adding this gives me one point in the middle of the screen so some success but not the random starry night. Also the colour of the point is black not white...

Comment: Then `gl.glOrtho( -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1 );`, your stars are between -1 and 1

Comment: Ok at then end, after you put all `vertexBuffer.put(...)`, you need to set the buffer position to the beginning. Updated the answer